# Dataframe borders with Python are not together

Tags: python, html, css

I have an issue with Python and the style of my dataframe. I would like my dataframe to look like a normal table, but fail to achieve the desired result.

So this is my Python code:

```
SummaryTable = {
                'Line': ['8a', '8b'],
                'Cost Center': ['Pharmacy not including Pharmaceuticals','Pharmaceuticals'],
                'Accrued Cost (a)': [sum_IngredientCost340b,0]
            }
            
            SummaryTable_df = p.DataFrame(SummaryTable)
            header_styles = [
                                {
                                'selector': 'th',
                                'props':[
                                            ('background-color', '#808080'),
                                            ('color', 'black'), 
                                            ('text-align', 'center'), 
                                            ('font-weight','bold'),
                                            ('border','1px solid black'),
                                            ('border-collapse','collapse'),
                                            ('border-spacing','0'),
                                            ('padding','5px'),
                                            ('margin','0px')
                                        ]
                                },
                                {
                                'selector': 'td', 
                                'props':[
                                            ('border','1px solid black'),
                                            ('border-collapse','collapse'),
                                            ('border-spacing','0'),
                                            ('padding','5px'),
                                            ('margin','0px')
                                        ]
                                }
                            ]
            SummaryTable_df = SummaryTable_df.style.set_table_styles(header_styles, axis=1)
           
            #Render HTML template for the results
            return render_template('reporte.html', data=SummaryTable_df.to_html(index=False))
```

Result:

[image: actual result]

I am getting those weird "blank spaces" between the borders of each cell, but I want this:

[image: desired result]

I want all borders to be together, like a table.

My `reporte.html` file is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Report</title>
    <style>
        .blank {
            display: none;
        }
        .row_heading {
            display: none;
        }   
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>ReportTest</h1>
    <table>
        {{ data | safe }}
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```